# Loop through array within an object and push to a new array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through an object's values that are an array and print out the names of dolls with a complete set matching either dollParts1 or dollParts2.

For example, if dollParts1 is in the parameter, ["Betty", "Alice"] should print out since those are the only dolls with all the specific parts (eyes, nose, mouth, ears).

But my solution is printing out all the doll's names and I can't figure out why. I feel like I am not using the break correctly. I also tried "return false" instead of break but that exits out of the for loop entirely, which I also do not want.

```
let dollObject = {
  Betty: [ 'feet', 'eyes', 'nose', 'ears', 'mouth' ],
  Carol: [ 'nose', 'nose', 'arms', 'nose', 'mouth' ],
  Lisa: [ 'eyes', 'nose', 'feet', 'hands' ],
  Alice: [ 'eyes', 'mouth', 'nose', 'ears', 'eyes' ]
}

let dollType1 = "eyes,nose,mouth,ears"
let dollType2 = "eyes,nose,mouth,ears,feet"

let result = []
let dollParts1 = dollType1.split(",")
let dollParts2 = dollType2.split(",")

function createDoll(whichPart) {
    for (doll in dollObject) {
      for (let i = 0; i < whichPart.length; i++) {
        if (!dollObject[doll].includes(whichPart[i])) {
          break;
        } 
      }
      result.push(doll)
    }
    console.log(result)
}

createDoll(dollParts1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop does nothing. This section

```
for (let i = 0; i < whichPart.length; i++) {
  if (!dollObject[doll].includes(whichPart[i])) {
    break;
  } 
}
```

may as well not be there at all, because none of the lines there actually *do* anything - whether you break out of the inner loop early or not makes no difference, because after the inner loop is done, you push the value anyway.

Check that `.every` one of a given doll name's parts is included in one of the dollType arrays.

```js
const dollObject = {
  Betty: [ 'feet', 'eyes', 'nose', 'ears', 'mouth' ],
  Carol: [ 'nose', 'nose', 'arms', 'nose', 'mouth' ],
  Lisa: [ 'eyes', 'nose', 'feet', 'hands' ],
  Alice: [ 'eyes', 'mouth', 'nose', 'ears', 'eyes' ]
}

let dollType1 = "eyes,nose,mouth,ears"
let dollType2 = "eyes,nose,mouth,ears,feet"

let result = []
let dollParts1 = dollType1.split(",")
let dollParts2 = dollType2.split(",")

function createDoll(whichPart) {
  return Object.keys(dollObject)
    .filter(name => whichPart.every(
      part => dollObject[name].includes(part)
    ));
}

console.log(createDoll(dollParts1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, you could use `every`, which checks if every parts are included in a doll

```js
let dollObject = {
  Betty: ["feet", "eyes", "nose", "ears", "mouth"],
  Carol: ["nose", "nose", "arms", "nose", "mouth"],
  Lisa: ["eyes", "nose", "feet", "hands"],
  Alice: ["eyes", "mouth", "nose", "ears", "eyes"],
}

let dollType1 = "eyes,nose,mouth,ears"
let dollType2 = "eyes,nose,mouth,ears,feet"

let dollParts1 = dollType1.split(",")
let dollParts2 = dollType2.split(",")

function createDoll(whichPart) {
  let result = []

  for (doll in dollObject) {
    if (whichPart.every(part => dollObject[doll].includes(part))) {
      result.push(doll)
    }
  }

  console.log(result)
}

createDoll(dollParts1)
```